# How to wrap text with auto fit specific table columns?

Tags: excel, vba, range, listobject

The following code works to wrap text and autofit the 2nd and 3rd column.  However, I get a runtime error 424 "object required" at the end.

```
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects(2)

With ws
    tbl.ListColumns(2).Range.WrapText = True
    tbl.ListColumns(2).Range.Rows.AutoFit = True
    tbl.ListColumns(3).Range.WrapText = True
    tbl.ListColumns(3).Range.Rows.AutoFit = True
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AutoFit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofit) is a method; remove the `= True`:

```
tbl.ListColumns(2).Range.Rows.AutoFit
...
tbl.ListColumns(3).Range.Rows.AutoFit
```